# Please remove dupe status

Tags: support, status-completed

A recent question of mine has been confused as a dupe:
[How can I be sure that the updated packages are not compromised?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278198/how-can-i-be-sure-that-the-updated-packages-are-not-compromised?noredirect=1#comment349456_278198)

The 'duped' question asks about Canonical repo security in the general sense. My question asks how to ensure that a particular package that I've already downloaded and installed is in fact secure, when there is general reason (i.e. an ongoing hack) and specific reason (i.e. Apt complaining) to suspect that a compromised package was installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had me at Please.

Yeah they're significantly different questions.

Comment: Thank you Oli.‏